# Incomplete printing in C

Tags: c, structure

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define max 3

struct t
{
    char ch;
    char cH;
    int i;
};

int main()
{
    struct t test[max];
    int count=0,in=0;

    while(count < max)
    {
        printf("Enter small char\n");
        scanf("%c",&test[count].ch);
        getchar();          

        printf("Enter big char\n");
        scanf("%c",&test[count].cH);
        getchar();

        printf("Enter number\n");
        scanf("%i",&test[count].i);
        count++;
    }

    for(in=0;in<count;in++)
    {
        printf("%c %c %i\n",test[in].ch,test[in].cH,test[in].i);
        //printf("line%10i\n",in);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For the following Input:

```
a A 1
b B 2
c C 3
```

Output:

```
a A 1
2
3
```

Why it is not printing line 2 and line 3.Is the error due to getchar() function?
Also is there any better to flush the input?

Comment: `scanf("%c", ...)` will read in the ENTERs. Try `scanf(" %c", ...)` to ignore whitespace (ENTER is whitespace) before "regular" characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read an integer the scanf keeps the '\n' in the buffer (when you press enter) which is captured by your next scanf. So, just add a new getchar() after reading the integer.

```
printf("Enter number\n");
scanf("%i",&test[count].i);
count++;
getchar();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also fix the problem by adding a space before the `%c` in the format specification. Then, there won't be a need to call `getchar()`.

```
while(count < max)
{
    printf("Enter small char\n");
    scanf(" %c",&test[count].ch);

    printf("Enter big char\n");
    scanf(" %c",&test[count].cH);

    printf("Enter number\n");
    scanf(" %i",&test[count].i);
    count++;
}
```